# React and TextInput disable mobile phone keyboard

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this code in React for normal web application.

```
<TextInput
  value={value}
  onFocus={onOpen}
  onClick={onOpen}
  label={t(label)}
  name={name}
/>

const onOpen = useCallback(() => {
    if (!value) {
      setDate(defaultAge ? new Date(defaultAge) : createDateObject({ month: 5, date: 15 }, true))
    }
    setOpen(true)
  }, [defaultAge, value])
```

I want to show my custom keyboard dialog and not Android native keyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by setting attribute readonly. Then native Android keyboard is not activated.

Answer (score 0):

Search in the entire project and remove this line.

```
<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
```

Comment: In my project is not any line like this.